# How do I center an OverlayEntry relative to a Widget on the screen in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, icons, tooltip, overlay, renderbox

I am struggling to figure out how to center a widget in an  `OverlayEntry` (inside an  `Overlay`) relative to another  `Widget` on the screen.

The following is a simplified version of the code I have up until now (assume it's a  `StatefulWidget` ):

```
class _MyIconState extends State<MyIcon> {
 
 // Here I get the RenderBox for the MyIcon widget and its size and coordinates
 late final renderedWidget = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
 late final renderedOffset = renderedWidget.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
 late final renderedSize = renderedWidget.size;

 // This is the OverlayEntry with the Text() Widget I'd love to center below MyIcon
 late final entry = OverlayEntry(
   builder: (context) => Positioned(
     top: renderedOffset.dy + renderedSize.height,
     left: renderedOffset.dx + (renderedSize.width / 2),
     child: Text(
         widget.message ?? 'Test',
         textAlign: TextAlign.center,
       ),
     ),
   ),
 );

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return widget.action != null
       ? GestureDetector(
           behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
           onTap: () {
             if (widget.action != null) {
               widget.action!();
               _showTooltip();
             } else {
               _showTooltip();
             }
           },
           child: Padding(
             padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
             child: Icon(widget.icon),
           ),
         )
       : Padding(
           padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
           child: Icon(widget.icon),
         );
 }

 _showTooltip() {
   // The screen overlay
   final overlay = Overlay.of(context)!;
   overlay.insert(entry);  
 }
}
```

Essentially, an `Overlay` is created and positions a tooltip `Text` (as an `OverlayEntry`) below the `MyIcon` when the icon itself is tapped.

The problem is this line of code: `renderedOffset.dx + (renderedSize.width / 2)`.

I can position the text in the tooltip to start below the middle of the `MyIcon`, but then the `Text` keeps being written to the right, appearing decentralized.

In order to center it, I'd need to position it like so: `renderedOffset.dx + (renderedSize.width / 2) - (renderedTextWidth/2)`, but the `Text` is dynamic and I see no way of knowing and accounting for its width (in the example, `renderedTextWidth`).

I am aware there is already a fine `Tooltip` widget in Flutter that would simplify my life. Unfortunately, some requirements (independent from the issue at hand) do not allow me to use it.
So I have to come up with something custom.

This is approximately what I end up with:
[I'd like the red lines to be more or less vertically aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHCTN.png)

Have you guys every faced such an issue or have some experience regarding something similar?
Do you have any tips on how to approach/solve the problem?

Thank you for any help.